# Widely Least Square Estimation

Tags: matrices, optimization, vectors, least-squares

I have an optimization problem as following 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\min\limits_{H,H^*}||y-AHx-BH^*x^*||^2\\
\text{such that:}\qquad Ax+Bx^*=g
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

in which

1. $(.)^*$ means conjugation.
2. $A$ and $B$ are $N \times N$ diagonal matrices.
3. $y$, $g$, and $x$ are $N \times 1$ column vectors
4. $H$ is an upper triangular matrix
5. Both vectors and matrices are generally complex

In the optimization problem, only $y$ and $g$ are known because they can be observed from experiments, while $A$, $B$, $x$ are unknown but having the constraint as in $g$

I've already tried to expand the $||.||$ in the objective function and then partially derived this function with $h_1,h_2,\text{etc}$, which are the elements of $H$, but it was too complicated and I got stuck.

Have any idea to resolve this problem? Thank you so much

Comment: Double check your constraint. $Bx^*$ is an illegal $(N\times N)\times (1\times N)$ matrix multiplication. Since $x$ is unknown, is the norm an operator norm, i.e. the supremum over all $\|x\|=1$?

Comment: @AlexR.: $(.)^*$ means conjugation, not conjugation transpose, so the dimension of $x^*$ is the same as $x$

Comment: @AlexR. Doesn't have any constraint for $x$